# Replace Specific String in YAML File using Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

I have a web application that uses a YAML file for configuration. This is an except from the file:

```
---
settings:
  domain: 127.0.0.1
```

I have an Ansible playbook that uses the lineinfile module to replace the IP address in the YAML file above with the server's public IP address.

```
- name: Discovering Public Internet Protocol Address
  ipify_facts:
  register: public_ip

- name: Configuring Application with discovered Public IP
  lineinfile:
    dest: /application/path/settings.yml
    regexp: '^(.*)domain: (.*)$'
    line: 'domain: {{ ipify_public_ip }}'
```

This finds and replaces the 127.0.0.1 IP with the public server's IP but it breaks the YAML indentation as follows:

```
---
settings:
domain: 54.12.33.3
```

Problem: "domain" is moved to the same line with "settings" and my ruby app fails to run migrations because it identifies a YAML syntax error.

I do not mind replacing lineinfile with another module, but I'd like to keep it if possible. I've been struggling with this for hours and will appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick solution, try to use the 2 spaces () for a better match and substitution:

```
    regexp: '^.*domain: (.*)$'
    line: '  domain: {{ ipify_public_ip }}'
```

I'm sure other improvements can be made to the regex, to use `\s` or `[:space:]`.

**UPDATE:** `.*` from the beginning of `regexp` shouldn't be needed. Updated per comment requested.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I updated the playbook according to your instructions (with 2 spaces) but it didn't work. This time, the line remained untouched.

Comment: Well, if you're regex (`'^  domain: (.*)$'`) does match your file it should work. You probably modified the file manually and through ansible. Will update my reply to take that into consideration.

Comment: At my first attempt, I noticed that it added additional domain: $ip lines at the bottom. I cleaned the file up and retired with your initial instructions and it modified it perfectly. I can't thank you enough. Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 3):

You could just create a yaml template verision.

```
- template:
    src: /path/to/settings.tpl.yml
    dest: /path/to/settings.yml
```

**settings.tpl.yml**

```
---
settings:
domain: {{ public_ip }}
```